# Borders around menu items disappearing

Tags: html, css, file

I'm having another issue. I can't figure where the issue is. I had added a border around my menu items. Everything was working fine until I added a logo. I believe the issue is with my .Main-Nav li a:hover. in my CSS. I'll post everything and see if you guys can figure it out. I would also like to know if I need to make a different file for every page on my website

```css
* {
  margin: 0PX;
  padding: 0PX;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/371794/pexels-photo-371794.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.hello {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 275px;
}

.button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 440px;
}

.btn {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn-one {
  background-color: darkorange;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two {
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
}

.btn-two:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<Head>
  <title> Drew's Blog</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" </head>

  <body>
    <header>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Oh-deer.png">
        </div>
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> ABOUT </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> GALLERY </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> NEWS </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> CONTACT </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> LESSONS </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="Hello">
        <h1> Lets Get Started</h1>

        <div class="button">
          <a href="" class="btn btn-one"> Get to Know Me</a>
          <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Check out my lessons</a>
        </div>


    </header>
  </body>


</html>
```

`

Comment: what you need to do? I am not getting you.

Comment: add this to your css
.main-nav li a{border: 1px solid white;}

Comment: When i hover over a menu item in my navigation bar, a border is supposed to appear around it.

Comment: Muzzamil301, It is already there. It was working, and then i changed something in my HTML(that shouldnt have effected it) and now it isnt working.

Comment: for some reason when i run my code on this website everything works, but not when i run it through Notepad++

Comment: you might linking wrong style.css while writing in notepad check it once..

Comment: I've only got one style.css file.

Comment: @DShannon3, Write the link tag correctly

Comment: the css link tag? To my knowledge it is written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  }
```

Add a:

```
border: 2px solid white;
```

This will put a border around your menu items that are put in the `<li>` tag

Look in the active class for the border:

```
.main-nav li.active a {
border: 2px solid white;
}
```

That's for the HOME button, because it's class is active (`class="active">`) and it already had a border

I changed the pixels so I can see the results, but the problem is exactly that: The pixels. If your `hover` pixels and `li` pixels are the same, you won't see any change

This should add a border to your menu items and change when you hover over them with the mouse.

Also, the

```
.main-nav li a:hover
```

does the exact opposite. When you define a border here and you HOVER OVER A MENU ITEM, a border will APPEAR, so basically try to balance the pixels out.

And I'm trying to figure out what exactly you want. Do you want borders to always be there and when you hover over them you want them to disappear or do you want borders to appear when you hover over them.

Comment: I'm sorry if i am confusing you. I want a border to be around the page I am on, I think you understand that part. I also want a border to appear around the other menu items when i hover over them. my bad. The hover border is only appearing around lesson.

Comment: Alright, now, would you say it works as expected when you paste your CSS and HTML code here: https://codepen.io/pen/ Notify me when you try your code here and it's still not working on your code as it should on that website